# UIImage View animation works one time... why?

Tags: xcode, animation, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm developing a game in Xcode 4.3.2

Ingame i need to call often this function to add two images on screen with an animation, first image enter from left, second from right and after 2 sec gone off:

```
-(void) PandaAnimation2 {
[pandablock3 removeFromSuperview];
[awesomeview removeFromSuperview];

//pandablock3 is a UIImageView
//awesomeview is a UIImageView
pandablock3.frame = CGRectMake(400, 101, 111, 208);
awesomeview.frame = CGRectMake(-400, 9, 230, 68);

[self addSubview:pandablock3];
[self addSubview:awesomeview];


[UIImageView beginAnimations:@"movein" context:NULL];
[UIImageView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIImageView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIImageView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIImageView setAnimationDuration:2.0];

pandablock3.frame = CGRectMake(208, 101, 111, 208);
awesomeview.frame = CGRectMake(11, 9, 230, 68);

[UIImageView commitAnimations];

[UIImageView beginAnimations:@"moveout" context:NULL];
[UIImageView setAnimationDelay:2.0];
[UIImageView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIImageView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIImageView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIImageView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

pandablock3.frame = CGRectMake(400, 101, 111, 208);
awesomeview.frame = CGRectMake(-400, 9, 230, 68);
[UIImageView commitAnimations];
```

}

it works good, but only ONE TIME! 
Why?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say witout looking what is calling your code, but my guess is `pandablock3`  and `awesomeview` get released after the first call and hence are `nil` in the second call.

Comment: ops... right! i need to define UIImageView into function! Thanks!